# If a sequence ${a_n}$ diverges to positive infinity, the number of non-positive terms is at most finite

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

For a while, I have tried to give a proof of the problem that "if a sequence $ \{ a_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ diverges to positive infinity, the number of non-positive terms is at most finite."
However, now I have no idea.

I tried to prove it like this.

> Since $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty $, for any real number $K$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N, a_n > K$.
> Here, we assume that the number of non-positive terms in $ \{a_n\} $ is not finite.
> ...

Can you help me with this problem and tell me how to prove it?

Comment: If there's an infinite number of negative numbers, there's a subsequence of negative numbers. Thus, $\lim\inf$ of the sequence is at most $0$.

Comment: Take $K=0$. What can you say about cardinality of $\{n: a_n \leq K\}$?

Comment: Don't do this by contradiction. There's no need.

Comment: Just think of the definition of  ‘$\lim_n a_n=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for all help.